# How to implement the rotate90 and distancefromto functions

Tags: java

Your PolarPoint class, , represents a point in terms of polar coordinates (radius from the origin and angle counterclockwise from the x-axis), both of type double.   Do not convert to Cartesian coordinates for any of the operations (except, of course, for xCoodinate and yCoordinate).  The rotate90 operation must return a new PolarPoint.

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class PolarPoint implements Point{


    private double radius;
    private double angle;

    public PolarPoint(double radius, double angle) {

        this.radius = radius;
        this.angle = angle;
     }

    public double angle()
    {
       return angle;
    }

    public double radius()
    {
       return radius;
    }

    public double xCoordinate()
    {
       return (radius * Math.cos(angle))  //Idk if its the right way
    }

    public double yCoordinate()
    {
       return (radius * Math.sin(angle))  //Idk if its the right way

    }

    public Point rotate90()
    {
      return angle() + 90.0  // Error
    }

    public double distanceFrom(Point other)
    {
          //Idk how to do this
    }
```

Comment: I was asking about how to implement the distancefrom because it has radius 1 and radius 2 in its formula

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when using methods `Math.cos(angle)` and `Math.sin(angle)`, parameter `angle` must be in radians, not in degrees, thats why adding 90.0 in `rotate90` method  will not give you desired behavior.

If you want to add 90.0 degrees in radiants, add `Math.PI/2`.

Try reading on polar coordinates [Complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) and [Polar coordinates distance](https://www.ck12.org/trigonometry/Distance-Between-Two-Polar-Coordinates/lesson/Distance-Between-Two-Polar-Coordinates/?referrer=concept_details)

Comment: Is the way that I implemented the x and y coordinate correct or would it be done in a different way?? Thanks for your help

Comment: @abdevilz the formulas you used are correct but if `angle` is in degrees instead of [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), you have to multiply by `Math.PI / 180.0` first: `radius * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180.0)` because `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` expect radians, not degrees.

Comment: To convert from degrees to radians, you have to multiply by `Math.PI / 180.0`, not "add `Math.PI/2`".

Comment: @Jesper, you are right, I was thinking about `rotate90` method when I talked about adding 90.0 degrees, I have edited my answer, thanks

Comment: Thanks guys 

So the rotate90() would be 
(angle * Math.PI/180.0) + Math.PI/2 ?

Comment: @abdevilz, if your angle member is in degrees, than you can just add + 90.0 (and then be careful to convert that angle to radians when using `Math.sin` and `Math.cos`). But if your angle member is in radians, then you can just add `Math.PI/2` because pi = 180°, so pi/2 = 90°. And be careful when you are using methods from `Math` class, always read method description closely!

Comment: Actually its in degrees

Comment: I get this error 
return angle() + 90.0;
                       ^
  required: Point
  found:    double